# How to create multiple submenu in submenu in WordPress admin?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to create multiple submenu in submenu in WordPress admin? I want to create submenu of submenu

Answer (score 0):

This should be a fairly easy thing to do.

After logging in to WordPress Dashboard (wp-admin), you need to navigate to Appearance -> Menus using left sidebar.

Now assume you have a menu called "Main Menu". There is already an item called "Contact Us!" under the main menu. First, you need to add your desired FIRST submenu item to the menu structure. Then just drag and drop it under the "Contact Us!" item.

Now just like before you need to add your SECOND menu item to the main structure. Then simply drag and drop it under the FIRST submenu item.

You can add virtually unlimited number of menus using this process.

Comment: i am not asking for navigation menu my question is regarding to admin left sidebar custom menu

Answer (score 0):

Currently Wordpress don't have that option but you can use accordion OR Tabs on admin page created for submenu as of current available options..